# Authoritative source of information: Which JDK version is supported by latest WildFly release?

Tags: java, wildfly, java-10

Is there an authoritative source for which WildFly application server version *fully* supports which version of Java?

In the official release information (http://wildfly.org/news/2018/05/30/WildFly13-Final-Released/) I just read vague hints ("Java 10 compatibilty has been improved").

Having some issues when deploying applications that run perfectly with Java 8, I would like to verify early, that in principle everything should be fine.

Comment: Not much better, but [this](http://docs.wildfly.org/13/Getting_Started_Guide.html#requirements) seems to imply it should be working under Java 10. From what I gather, modularity support is still limited, but that doesn't mean that the application server will fail to work with Java9/10.

Comment: Realize that most organizations are not going to put much work into Java 9 and 10.  Java 9 is no longer supported by Oracle and Java 10 won't be by September of 2018.  Java 11, coming out in September of 2018, will be another long term support release like Java 8.  As a vendor it is difficult to spend time testing and supporting releases with such a short lifespan (Java 9 and 10 were/are supported for about 7 months each).

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and then come back with what doesn't work for you? *Having some issues when deploying applications* ...needs to be elaborated/described. Why not read the duplicate link's answer for example.

Comment: @nullpointer: We have already solved several specific problems. In the process of solving those problems we asked ourselves if we were just holding it wrong or if we simply should not expect all problems to be solved already.